# I want to dynamically insert a comma into UITextField for ios Swift3

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, number-formatting

Attempt to change the character of UITextField using NumberFormat failed.

Number: 1000000.00

Result:

- 1.00
- 1,0.00
- 10,0.00
- 100,0.00
- 1,000,0.00
- 100,000,0.00
- 1,000,000,0.00

How can I convert?

Here is my code that failed.

```
public func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

if ((string == "0" || string == "") && (textField.text! as NSString).range(of: ".").location < range.location) {
    return true
}

let cs = NSCharacterSet(charactersIn: "0123456789.").inverted
let filtered = string.components(separatedBy: cs)
let component = filtered.joined(separator: "")
let isNumeric = string == component

if isNumeric {
    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
    formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 0

    let newString = (textField.text! as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)
    let numberWithOutCommas = newString.replacingOccurrences(of: ",", with: "")
    let number = formatter.number(from: numberWithOutCommas)
    if number != nil {
        var formattedString = formatter.string(from: number!)

        if string == "." && range.location == textField.text?.characters.count {
            formattedString = formattedString?.appending(".")
        }

        /* // Fail...
        if length! > 1 { 
            formattedString?.insert(",", at: (formattedString?.index((formattedString?.endIndex)!, offsetBy: -1))!) 
        }
        */

        textField.text = formattedString
    } else {
        textField.text = nil
    }
}
return false
```

}

Comment: Can u add objective-c version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it with the following code.

```
if ((string == "0" || string == "") && (textField.text! as NSString).range(of: ".").location < range.location) {
                return true
            }

            let cs = NSCharacterSet(charactersIn: "0123456789.").inverted
            let filtered = string.components(separatedBy: cs)
            let component = filtered.joined(separator: "")
            let isNumeric = string == component

            if isNumeric {
                let newString = (textField.text! as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)
                let numberWithOutCommas = newString.replacingOccurrences(of: ",", with: "")

                var charSum = 1;

                var resultStr: String = ""

                for (_, element) in numberWithOutCommas.characters.reversed().enumerated() {
                    resultStr.append(element)
                    if charSum % 3 == 1 {
                        resultStr.append(",")
                    }
                    charSum += 1
                }

                var str = String(resultStr.characters.reversed())

                if str.characters.count > 0 {
                    if str[str.startIndex] == "," {
                        str.remove(at: str.startIndex)
                    }
                }
                textField.text = str
            }
            return false
```

Comment: Can you share objective-c version for this

Answer (score 1):

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
        var value = textField.text
        var components = value.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "1234567890,.").invertedSet)
        var decimalString = "".join(components) as NSString

        let number = NSDecimalNumber(string: decimalString, locale:NSLocale.currentLocale())

        var formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterStyle.CurrencyStyle
        formatter.locale = NSLocale.currentLocale()

        if let formatedValue = formatter.stringFromNumber(number) {
            textField.text = formatedValue
        }
        else {
            textField.text = ""
        }
}
```

Comment: '100,000,0.00' should be the same result. Take a good look at the comma

Answer (score 0):

Use `Numberformatter` for currency formate text:

```
var formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle
formatter.locale = NSLocale.currentLocale()
print("\(formatter.stringFromNumber(number)!)")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let number = 1000000.00
let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
numberFormatter.numberStyle = NumberFormatter.Style.decimal
numberFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: number))

let str  =  numberFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: number))
print (str is ---%@",str)
output ---> 1,000,000
```

Comment: '100,000,0.00' should be the same result. Take a good look at the comma

Comment: I am not getting your point 100,000,0.00' should be the same result.

Comment: It will insert comma according values